# update pip in windows

Tags: python-3.x, pip, windows-8.1, anaconda

**Environment:**

`Python 3.5.2
Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)
Windows 8.1`

I tried to update pip using `easy_intall -U pip` in **cmd**.

**Error:**

```
The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the installation directory:

[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Program Files\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\test-easy-install-4760.write-test'The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or the distutils default setting) was: C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, but on Windows 7 and above, program files requires administrator privilege.

I installed Anaconda on `c:\anaconda` so I don't have such problems. You can try it.

But before this, try running the console in administrator privilege. In the start menu type `cmd`, then windows will show you `Command Prompt` application.Right click and activate it as administrator. Then try to update pip.

Answer (score -1):

Try right click on Command prompt icon and select run as administrator. Worked for me in similar cases.